# Cannot reference to a form control which is out of focus

Tags: ms-access, textbox, focus, vba

This is a follow up to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11986227/update-textbox-during-typing) I asked about how to update a textbox while typing. In my previous question, I had three textboxes, two of which were enabled and one which was not. They look like this:

[image: Three textbox image]

My goal is to use the First and Last Name of the two textboxes to fill a "Code Personal" in the other textbox. As I type the first and last names, I want the Code Personal textbox to update immediately, with the format of **LLLLLL_F** (eg: BERNAS_P). However, whenever I try to update the Code Personal textbox, I receive this error:

[image: Error image]

The code I use to create the Code Personal format and to update the textbox is:

```
Private Sub TxtFName_Change()

firstName = Me.TxtFName.Value
lastName = Me.txtLName.Value
firstPart = Left(lastName, 6)
secondPart = Left(firstName, 1)

nameCode = firstPart + "_" + secondPart
upperNameCode = UCase(nameCode)

txtCodePersonal.Text = upperNameCode 'My debug tells me I have an error here
End Sub
```

I've tried to set the focus to the *txtCodePersonal* textbox through: `[txtCodePersonal].SetFocus`, but I still receive an error (MS Access can't move the focus to the control *txtCodePersonal*.)

Any Ideas as to how I can update the "Code Personal" textbox while typing in the other two textboxes?

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do your value assignment to the text box's `.Value` property instead of its `.Text` property.  Either of these should work:

```
Me.txtCodePersonal.Value = upperNameCode
Me.txtCodePersonal = upperNameCode
```

`.Value` is the default property for a text box, so you don't need to include it explicitly.  Include it if you feel it makes the code clearer.

Comment: This problem was addressed in my [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11986227/update-textbox-during-typing). The `.Value` property doesn't update the _txtCodePersonal_ textbox while typing. Only the `.Text` property does this.

Comment: For `TxtFName_Change()`, you need to reference the `.Text` property of TxtFName, not the `.Text` property of `txtCodePersonal`.

Comment: Ahh, I see, I had it the wrong way around. Thank you, that works! Although, now I am presented with the error of `lastName = Me.txtLName.Text` being out of focus. Any ideas for combining the first 6 letters of LName and the first letter of FName now that I can't include `Me.txtLName.Text` in the `TxtFName_Change()` sub?

Comment: I'm unsure whether I've missed something important here, but I think you should try: `lastName = Me.txtLName.Value`

Comment: My instinct would be not to bother updating `txtCodePersonal` for each keystroke in `TxtFName`.  Instead, set the control source for `txtCodePersonal` to `=UCase(Left([txtLName],6) & "_" & Left([TxtFName], 1))` That way, `txtCodePersonal` would be automagically updated to reflect completed changes to `TxtFName` or `txtLName` ... but the update wouldn't happen with each keystroke.

Comment: In fact, your previous comment in which you suggested to use `lastName = Me.txtLName.Value` works perfectly. I updates with each keystroke and the final result is exactly what I wanted. I understand why you other reasoning, and will take that into consideration when I finish the form. thanks again.